# Removing displayed data from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This is what 'new' button does in my entry form, in addition to this, i want it to remove all displayed data from JTable. How can i do that?

```
   saved = false;
   txt_ipath.setText(null);
   txt_md_by_p.setText(null);
   txt_model_p.setText(null);
   txt_p_date.setText(sdf.format(date));
   txt_p_price.setText(null);
   txt_p_qty.setText(null);
   txt_s_price_p.setText(null);
   txt_vouchdate_p.setText(sdf.format(date));
   txt_vouchno_p.setText(null);
```

Comment: Remove the data from the `TableModel`, and the `JTable` should update automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a DefaultTableModel for your JTable you can just use:

```
model.setRowCount(0);
```

Or, if you are removing a row of data you can use:

```
model.removeRow(...);
```

any changes to the data should be done via the model.

Comment: I made my DefaultTableModel object tblModel as global and tried to do whta you suggested but now i get NullPointerException.  

       tblModel.setRowCount(0);

Comment: Then obviously you global reference doesn't actually reference the table model that is being used by the table. I can't help because I am not a mind reader and I have not idea what your code looks like. There is no need to make the model a global variable. You can always get the model from the JTable.

Comment: got it, i was setting the rows to 0 without getting the model. its working now, thanks.